# Pass null value for date in SQL query in Oracle through Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, hibernate

I'm having trouble passing a null value for date in my sql query. The part which causes the problem is as below:

```
....
WHERE (s.CREATED_DATE BETWEEN (CASE WHEN ?1 IS NULL THEN ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(sysdate), -500) ELSE ?1 END) AND (CASE WHEN ?2 IS NULL THEN sysdate ELSE ?2 END))
....
```

When i pass a null value for date in parameters via Hibernate, i get this infamous error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY
```

I have reviewed the previous questions on this matter in stackoverflow but the solutions can't seem to be working for me. This query is run as a native query by hibernate throught spring's @Query annotation. Is there any way to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
I found out that if I place the @Temporal annotation besides @Param, then spring will automatically parse the date if it's null. The problem is I won't be able to use LocalDateTime and there will only be SQL Date with no time.
my repository method is like this:

```
@Query("The query mentioned above", nativeQuery=true)
Optional<SomeDTO> getNeededInfo(@Temporal @Param("after")Date after, @Temporal @Param("before") Date before)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting Parameters to this Query, you will need to use the 3 parameter method as such:

```
setParameter(1, date1, TemporalType.DATE);
setParameter(2, date2, TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: No, I'm not using a setter. The @Query which is positioned on top of my method sets the parameters itself when the method is called. FYI my method is like this: "Optional<SomeObject> getValue(LocalDateTime after, LocalDateTime before);"

Comment: I would recommend keeping the Queries simple and doing null logic in the application to avoid this issue in the first place. For the issue with LocalDateTime, you need to use something supporting JPA 2.2. Which is hibernate 5.1+